# Finding two hidden elements with Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to find two hidden elements in my website. I tried to find it by using XPath, DOM ID, and a CSS selector but I haven't succeeded.

Here's my code: (there's a HTML comment after the elements in question)

```
<style type="text/css">
<ul id="nav" class="Navul">
  <li id="li_1" class="menuActive" lname="Mnu_Home">
  <li id="li_2" lname="Mnu_Task">
  <li id="li_3" lname="Mnu_Sales">
  <div class="DetailHolderMenu">
    <div id="topnav4" class="topnav4">
      <a href="#">
        Sales<span></span>
      </a>
  </div>
<div class="DetailContainerMenu w170" style="font-weight: lighter; display: none;">
  <div class="ChildLinks">
    <ul class="lsn">
      <li id="li_3_1"> <!-- ELEMENT I'M TRYING TO FIND -->
        <a href="/Web/ProductRender/Index?childProductId=Product.Achilles_GBO.WIP&childComponentId=Supplier On Boarding&schemaId=Schema.4776.WIP&productId=Product.Achilles_GBO.WIP&communityId=TxnyD.Communities.2.1&index=3&childIndex=3_1">Prospects</a> <!-- OTHER ELEMENT -->
        <span></span>
      </li>
```

Comment: Please correct the html format.

Comment: Webdriver findElement can't find out hidden element. But there are ways to validate whether an element is visible or not. Please clarify what you want to achieve here. Will give you direction accordingly.

Comment: Hi MfSi_Sitamj <br> Well i want to find my hidden dynamic id .<br> and that id i already mentioned in above script as <li id = "li_3_1"> this id im not able to indeify by using selenium webdriver.i tried to find out by using id,text,partial text,css,xpath,...but nothing worked for me...so how can i identify this id for this i need help please send me ur email id here im facing bit difficulty to paste my enitre script .if i will get your email id i will forward you entire script ...

Answer (score 1):

After clicking on Sales link whether prospects link visible?
Do you
   need to do any other action to click on prospects link (say mouse
   hover) ?

Try with below logic

```
//click on Sales link    
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='topnav4']/a[text()='Sales']")).click();

//click prospects
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'DetailContainerMenu')]//li[@id='li_3_1']//a[text()='Prospects']")).click();
```

Comment: Hi Its working Now Finaly... Thanks a lots Santosh and All other who helped me ...

Answer (score 0):

Webdriver can find hidden element but it doesn't allow to work with it. 
I don't know why you can't find it by LinkText, so try to find it in the next way:

```
element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("li_3_1")).FindElement(By.TagName("a"));
```

Comment: got following issue now <br>

FAILED: f

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: 

{"method":"id","selector":"li_3_1"}

Command duration or timeout: 29 milliseconds

For documentation on this error, please visit: 
http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:11:15'

System info: host: 'ABGPC0066', ip: '10.187.3.191', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', 
os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_20'